# ImageView - foreground vs. background drawable

Tags: android, imageview

In reviewing the code of an App, I see that it uses the background image setting for an ImageView with an empty foreground image:

```
staticon.setImageResource(0);
staticon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.switch_to_on);
```

What are the pro's and cons of this approach? Will it be safe to refactor this to just use the foreground image? The drawable being set is a Frame Animation.

Comment: Clarification: When I ask about safety, I mean will I get the same behaviour from a foreground drawable as I did with the background? Will this cause layout issues or image scaling or performance issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is safe.All the widgets are designed in the way you can use according to your requirement.I dont think any unsafe situation in this code. :)

Comment: Thanks. When I asked "safe", I meant will I get the same behaviour from a foreground drawable as I did with the background? Will this cause layout issues or image scaling or performance issues?

Comment: nothing it will create just whatever the layout sizes will be given.

Answer (score 4):

A background image may be set on any view object and is stretched to the size of the view. The image resource is for ImageView only and allows you to scale and have more control over the image. You can use scale type to adjust how the image is displayed.

Comment: Your generic description does not answer my question: is it safe to make this change.